# Escaping parentheses in XPATH (document.evaluate)

Tags: javascript, xpath, document.evaluate

I am using the following code to iterate over all DOM elements that contain a phone number.  This code works when the phone number string being searched for does not have any parentheses in it, but I assume the parentheses is messing up the XPATH contains() function.  Does anyone have any idea on how I can escape these parentheses to make the code work again?

```
var oldPhoneNumber = '(123) 456-7890';
if (document.evaluate) {
    var nextElement = document.evaluate("//text()[contains(.,\"" + oldPhoneNumber + "\")]", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null).iterateNext();
    while (nextElement) {
        nextElement = document.evaluate("//text()[contains(.,\"" + oldPhoneNumber + "\")]", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null).iterateNext();
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can't see why the parentheses should cause the failure. What are the symptoms?

Note that constructing XPath expressions by string concatenation is bad form. Two main reasons: you're exposed to injection attacks, and you have to recompile the expression every time it is used. Much better to have expressions that contain variables, compile the expression once, and supply a value for the variable each time the expression is executed.

But you're in Javascript so you may not have much choice (unless you move to Saxon-JS, of course).

(Later) Thinking again about what could cause this, a couple of possibilities come to mind. Perhaps the spaces in the phone number are actually non-breaking spaces? Perhaps the DOM is not normalized and the phone numbers are split across multiple text nodes? (It's always best to avoid using `text()`. Try `//*[contains(., '....')]` instead.)